# How to save a grayscale image in Qt 5

Tags: image, qt, save, qt5

I am having trouble getting Qt5 to save a grayscale `Format_Indexed8` image.
When I save the file I get a polychromatic mess with no relevant features. I am expecting a gray-scale BMP.

The monochrome image is stored as `sizeof(uchar)*widthGL*heightGL`.

```
glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,0,0,widthGL,heightGL,
                GL_LUMINANCE,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,noise);
//computation   
QImage mySurface(noise,widthGL,heightGL,QImage::Format_Indexed8);
mySurface.save("test.bmp","BMP");
```

My current work around involves using a second array and feels dirty

```
static unsigned char* mbuffer = new unsigned char[3*widthGL*heightGL];
for (int i = 0,bpos=0;i<widthGL*heightGL;i++)
{
mbuffer[bpos++]=noise[i];
mbuffer[bpos++]=noise[i];
mbuffer[bpos++]=noise[i];
}
QImage mySurface(mbuffer,widthGL,heightGL,QImage::Format_RGB888);
```

I was wondering if there was any way to get Qt5 to output something resembling a grayscale image.

EDIT

> There is a reasonable chance this problem is solved in the latest
>   version of Qt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Newer version  of Qt introduced `Format_Grayscale8`, so that an eight bit grayscale image can be saved like:

```
QImage mySurface(noise,widthGL,heightGL,QImage::Format_Grayscale8);
mySurface.save("test.bmp","BMP");
```

I revisited this issue when I noticed the approach proposed by @owacoder actually started to produce invalid BMP files that didn't open with ImageJ or Paint (for whatever reason).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not setting the color table in the image before you use it. From the Qt docs (http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html#QImage-4):

> If format is an indexed color format, the image color table is initially empty and must be sufficiently expanded with setColorCount() or setColorTable() before the image is used.

You can try this:

```
glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,0,0,widthGL,heightGL,GL_LUMINANCE,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,noise);
//computation
QVector<QRgb> colorTable(256); //our grayscale palette
QImage mySurface(noise,widthGL,heightGL,QImage::Format_Indexed8);
for (int i = 0; i < 256; ++i)
     colorTable[i] = qRgb(i, i, i); //build palette
mySurface.setColorCount(256);
mySurface.setColorTable(colorTable);
mySurface.save("test.bmp","BMP");
```